# Postgres: Use result of group by as column names

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I have a messages table in a database, which include a sender id and a message type (and of course many more columns not relevant for this question). I try to create a query which counts how many messages of each type a user have send.

e.g. if I have the following table:

```
---------------------------
id | user_id | message_type
---------------------------
1  | 1       | private
2  | 1       | public
3  | 1       | private
---------------------------
```

Then I want to get the following:

```
---------------------
id | private | public
---------------------
1  | 2       | 1
---------------------
```

So in fact I want to group by message_type and user_id, but instead of generating multiple rows per user, I want to create multiple columns, one for each message_type

Can I achieve this without hardcoding the message types in my query?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a limited number of values that you want to convert into columns, then this can easily be implemented using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select user_id,
  sum(case when message_type = 'private' then 1 else 0 end) private,
  sum(case when message_type = 'public' then 1 else 0 end) public
from yourtable
group by user_id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/4c1d5/2)

PostgreSQL has the ability to use a `crosstab()` that can be used by installing the [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html) module.  This will perform a similar data transformation from rows into columns. Creating a dynamic version of the query is not a straight forward process, here is a great solution for a [dynamic crosstab on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506199/dynamic-alternative-to-pivot-with-case-and-group-by/15514334#15514334).

Answer (score 4):

PostgreSQL doesn't directly support PIVOT, which is the keyword usually used on other platforms for something like this.  It *does* have some crosstab functions in the [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) module.

[Using the crosstab() function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751905/562459), (an excellent StackOverflow answer)