# Using start and end event logs to create a table/view containing spans between the times of each log

Tags: postgresql, pivot, redshift, aggregate-filter

To be specific, I have an event table that logs when a user joins or leaves a team.  It looks something like the following:

```
-------------------------------------
| user | event  | team | timestamp |
-------------------------------------
| A    | joined | 1    | 2016-1-1  |
| B    | joined | 1    | 2016-1-1  |
| C    | left   | 1    | 2016-1-1  |
| C    | joined | 2    | 2016-1-1  |
| A    | left   | 1    | 2016-1-2  |
| A    | joined | 2    | 2016-1-2  |
| B    | left   | 1    | 2016-1-3  |
| A    | left   | 2    | 2016-1-3  |
-------------------------------------
```

I need to restructure this in a view to look something like the following

```
--------------------------------------
| user | team | joined    | left     |
--------------------------------------
| A    | 1    | 2016-1-1  | 2016-1-2 |
| A    | 2    | 2016-1-2  | 2016-1-3 |
| B    | 1    | 2016-1-1  | 2016-1-3 |
| C    | 1    | null      | 2016-1-1 |
| C    | 2    | 2016-1-1  | null     |
--------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve this?

For more detail, I'm attempting to do this in Amazon Redshift (PostgreSQL)

Comment: do you have a scenario where a user joins and leaves a team multiple times?

Comment: Please also provide your table definition showing data types and all constraints. Can we rely on data integrity? Can we assume that `joined` always comes before the associated `left`? Can a user join the same team repeatedly (which would prohibit a simple `GROUP BY` + `CASE` solution).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming all columns `NOT NULL`. And 'left' is never earlier than the associated 'joined'.

### Simple case

If users can join teams only *once* (which would be enforced by a `UNIQUE` constraint on `("user", team)`, ideally), then the solution is a simple `GROUP BY` and works in Redshift as well as in most any RDBMS:

```
SELECT "user", team
     , min(CASE WHEN event = 'joined' THEN timestamp END) AS joined
     , max(CASE WHEN event = 'left'   THEN timestamp END) AS "left"
FROM   event
GROUP  BY "user", team
ORDER  BY "user", joined NULLS FIRST;
```

Note the `NULLS FIRST` clause. Seems like you want to sort an open start with `joined IS NULL` first. [Redshift supports that, too.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ORDER_BY_clause.html)

Apart from that it's the most basic form of a crosstab / pivot query.

### Not so simple

Judging from your column names and example data it **might not be so simple**. If users **can join teams more than once** (non-overlapping), you have to do more. You wouldn't want to merge multiple team memberships into one row like in this related answer:

- [Postgres: Use result of group by as column names](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/38758/postgres-use-result-of-group-by-as-column-names/38766#38766)

Instead you have to pair up adjacent 'joined' and 'left' rows *somehow*. There are many ways ...

#### Postgres 9.4+

For modern Postgres I like this best:

```
SELECT "user", team
     , min(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE event = 'joined') AS joined
     , max(timestamp) FILTER (WHERE event = 'left'  ) AS "left"
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE event = 'joined')
                      OVER (PARTITION BY "user", team ORDER BY timestamp) AS ct
   FROM   event
   ) sub
GROUP  BY "user", team, ct
ORDER  BY "user", joined NULLS FIRST;
```

Using the aggregate `FILTER` clause in a window function as well as in an aggregate function. Related (with links to alternatives):

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

This way we count how many times the same user joined the same team, so we can group adjacent rows. Works for a missing `'joined'` at the begin or a missing `'left'` at the end as well.

#### Redshift

... does not support the new `FILTER` clause. We can substitute with a plain old `CASE`:

```
SELECT "user", team
     , min(CASE WHEN event = 'joined' THEN timestamp END) AS joined
     , max(CASE WHEN event = 'left'   THEN timestamp END) AS "left"
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(CASE WHEN event = 'joined' THEN 1 END)
                      OVER (PARTITION BY "user", team ORDER BY timestamp, event) AS ct
   FROM   event
   ) sub
GROUP  BY "user", team, ct
ORDER  BY "user", joined NULLS FIRST;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e4262/3)

---

**Aside:** you shouldn't use [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers, even if it's permitted by Redshift (or Postgres).

Answer (score 2):

You can use *conditional aggregation* in order to get 'joined' / 'left' values:

```
SELECT "user", team, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'joined' THEN timestamp END) AS joined,
       MAX(CASE WHEN event = 'left' THEN timestamp END) AS left
FROM mytable
GROUP BY "user", team
ORDER BY "user", team
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/efaad/4)

Comment: I like this, but would this be accurate in the case that a user had left and then rejoined a team?  It appears to me as though it would just find the first time they joined and last time they left.  Could this be tweaked for that edge case?

Answer (score 1):

To handle cases when a user joins and leaves a team multiple times, you can do

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f23d9/2)

```
with joins as 
(select *, row_number() over(partition by "user", team order by timestamp) as rn
from mytable
where "event" = 'joined')
, leaves as 
(select *, row_number() over(partition by "user", team order by timestamp) as rn
from mytable
where "event" = 'left')
select coalesce(j.user,l.user) as "user", coalesce(j.team,l.team) as team, 
j.timestamp as joined, l.timestamp as lefton
from joins j
full join leaves l on l.rn = j.rn and j.user = l.user and j.team = l.team
```

Used Giorgos Betsos fiddle for the schema.