# Restructure create and delete events on rows into single table

Tags: mysql, postgresql, google-bigquery

Similar to this problem: [Using start and end event logs to create a table/view containing spans between the times of each log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125930/using-start-and-end-event-logs-to-create-a-table-view-containing-spans-between-t).

I have table that logs 'create' and 'delete' events for a resource that corresponds to an object.

Every event:

- Is it's own row
- Has a unique ID
- Has a timestamp of when it occurred.

```
-------------------------------------
| id   | type   |object| timestamp |
-------------------------------------
| 1    | create | A    | 2019-1-1  |
| 2    | create | A    | 2019-1-2  |
| 3    | delete | A    | 2019-1-2  |
| 4    | create | B    | 2019-1-1  |
| 5    | delete | B    | 2019-1-2  |
| 6    | create | A    | 2019-1-3  |
| 7    | create | B    | 2019-1-4  |
| 8    | create | C    | 2019-1-5  |
-------------------------------------
```

The question I want to answer is how many resources still exist for a given object.

Example:

According to the data in the sample table, Object 'A' still has 2 resources that exist (three where created, one  was deleted.).  Object B and C each have one remaining resource.

Is it possible (as in the linked problem) to restructure this in a view where I have create and delete columns with timestamps?

Comment: You seem to have two different questions. _"how many resources still exist for a given object"_ vs. _"restructure this in a view"_. Which is it? What would the view look like given your sample data? Which `A` is being deleted in the event with `id=3`?

Answer (score 0):

No restructure is needed.  (Or I don't understand why there might need to be a restructure.)

```
SELECT  object,
        SUM(type = 'create') - SUM(type = 'delete') AS remaining_ct
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY object;
```

This assumes that 'creates' occur before 'deletes'.